# Unable to compile openFrameworks

Tags: c++, openframeworks

While trying to set up OF on eclipse (linux mint 17), I keep getting the following error :[image]

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++14’
```

I cannot find a solution online. I have tried updating my g++, replacing my libs/frameworks/video files with the latest on github, but nothing seems to work.

Though this issue has been closed [here](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/3205), i am unable to solve mine.

Is there a way to change the make file so that it builds successfully?

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: Im using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g++ doesn't support -std=c++14 until 4.9

See (for example) https://askubuntu.com/questions/428198/getting-installing-gcc-g-4-9-on-ubuntu for how to install 4.9 on Ubuntu

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04
This really helped me.

Comment: Though it has built successfully, I am now unable to see openFrameWorks in the preferences window.
https://vimeo.com/143111040
2:01 on the video.